# Can javascript be used with ASP:GridView (Controls)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-3.0

Seeing as i am new to ASP.NET Controls, this question may seem a bit easy, but i have yet to find a good resource.    I am using an ASP:GridView to display data coming from a custom Web Service.  The GridView is inside an ASP:Panel. One column we want to click/select a row,  the results will be that one panel will hide and another will be visible.  The field I am using right now is HyperLinkField but i cannot use javascript.   Is there another ASP control that uses javascript or a workaround?

This is a VisualWebpart

Here is the code i am using right now inside the  "ascx.cs":

```
HyperLinkField myHyperLink = new HyperLinkField();
myHyperLink.DataTextField = "Name";
myHyperLink.SortExpression = "Name";
myHyperLink.HeaderText =  "Name";
spgvEmployeeList.Columns.Add(myHyperLink);
myHyperLink.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "data-name";
myHyperLink.ItemStyle.CssClass = "data-name";
myHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "javascript:hidePanel";
```

Comment: Have a look at this article **http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-show-hide-visible-hyperlink.html**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript on your `HyperLink` controls. Use the `RowDataBound()` event and call the `FindControl()` method of the Row to find the `HyperLink` control. Once you obtain the Instance of your control, you can modify it's attributes by using the `Attributes` property of the `HyperLink` control. You can add any Javascript here.

Good luck!